# sharepoint central adminstration login error " cannot complete this action please try again."

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, wss-3.0-sp2

I install sharepoint 2007 stand alone on windows server 2008 and then i install WSS 3.0 Sp2. but after install wss 3.0 sp2 i can't able to login in sharepoint central adminstration website getting error :

Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.

please help me waiting for reply..

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the configuration wizard after installing the service pack? This is required. Your sites are not accessible until you successfully run the wizard.